# Keep Sprite From Speeding Up

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit, when I repeat the `moveTo` action on a sprite, it begins to accelerate when the key has been pressed for more than a second or so. Here is the code:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let key = theEvent.keyCode
    print(key)
    let mario = self.childNodeWithName("mario")
    if key == 0 {
        mario?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(-1, 0), duration: 0.01)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever looked at the docs, you will see that there is a `hasActions` method that tells you whether the `SKNode` is executing an action. You can use this method to prevent the node from running another move action while it is moving:

```
if let marioNode = mario {
    if key == 0 && !marioMode.hasActions() {
        marioNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(-1, 0), duration: 0.01)))
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what `hasActions`, I just didn't implement it the right way I believe. Thank you

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it. @AbhiV

Comment: Just tried it out once to make sure it was right and it works